# Automatically mount on fstab

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

I have a system.bin whici is located in /mnt and i want to automatically mount by edtiting fstab on /mnt/mymount with read and write permissions for all users on system

i try adding this on fstab:

UUID=c4649367-f47c-4c31-9b33-cb4b37083ae5 /mnt/mymnt ext2 rw,auto

but is not working

Comment: Okay, and what problems are you having with it?

Comment: What happens if you type `mount /mnt/mymount`?

Comment: @davidbaumann mount: /mnt/mymnt: can't find in /etc/fstab.

Comment: So there must be a typo.

Comment: type of system.bin is ext2

Answer (score 0):

Well that is just a typo, because the mount point is `/mnt/mymount` but the mount point in your fstab file is `/mnt/mymnt`.